# How to have my stock GS3 dialer initial screen be Recent instead of Keypad

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, stock-android, phone-app

Is it possible to have the stock dialer on my GS3 start on the Recent tab instead of the Keypad tab?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this? I have the exact question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an app called xshortcut (in Google Play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ex.chinyang.android.xshortcut )

Follow the following steps:

1. Install xshortcut **2.0.x**
2. Open xshortcut's Editor.
3. Switch to Component page
4. Use the following data to create the shortcut you want.

   Component Package: com.android.contacts

   Component Class: com.android.contacts.activities.DialtactsActivity

   MIME Type: vnd.android.cursor.dir/calls